# Do We Need Non-Constructible Sets?

Tags: set-theory

I was reading about Godel's Constructible Universe in which the Continuum Hypothesis and Axiom of Choice are true.  It made me wonder, what kind of math would we be unable to do if every set were constructible.  Would we lose any important theorems?  Although I welcome results from set theory, I would like results that would have an effect on branches such as analysis, topology, or algebra.  Thanks.

Comment: The vast majority of day-to-day mathematics is a consequence of ZFC, and ZFC is true in the constructible universe.  You could look for results that depend on the continuum hypothesis being false.

Comment: Descriptive set theoretic properties that depend on large cardinals can fail in the Constructible $L$. These includes determinacy and perfect set properties for certain definable subsets of the reals.

Comment: This is a buffed up version of the question "Do we need infinite sets", or do we need "uncountable sets" or do we need "sets larger than the continuum", or so on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It may be buffed up.  But, it is fairly obvious to me that we need the natural numbers or the real numbers.  But, how much do we need?  And, isn't it nice to have the Continuum Hypothesis (at least it feels nice)?

Comment: The question is what you are trying to achieve. If you really just want to do non-set theory related math, then sure, $V=L$ is a nice axiom. Maybe even an overkill, since you really just need much much much less for most things.

Comment: Since nobody was bold enough to answer your question,  I guess we can say, in regards to the mathematical 'playground' L - "that's all she wrote". Well, I guess "he wrote" in this instance. Real world results outside of L? lol